# Logging with Castle Windsor, the Logging Facility and log4net

Tags: log4net, castle-windsor

My code is :

log4net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="MyLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\log-file.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyWayLog" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

LoggerInstaler.cs

```
public class LoggerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config"));
    }
}
```

MyLogger.cs

```
private static ILoggerFactory loggera = IoC.Container.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();

private static ILogger logger = loggera.Create("MyLog"); 

public static ILogger Log
{
    get { return logger; }
    set { logger = value; }
}
```

When I Use `Log.Error("some exception")`

In log file I have other logs from some other dll. I want only my logs, not the other dll exception, only explicitly from call (Log.Error).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
<logger name="MyLog">
```

instead of

```
<root>
```

in the log4net.config

You may also use ToLog method within windsor regitration

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config").ToLog("MyLog"));
```

Not sure about your MyLogger.cs: Due to windsor facility, there's should no need for that...
simply set `ILogger` as dependency when you need it